# Как побороть org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

Перебираю элементы итератором по css локаторам

```
util.elementVisible(countryButton).click;// нажимаем на pop-up кнопку

List<WebElement> currencyDrop = driver.findElements(ListOfCurrency);
    Iterator<WebElement> iteratorCurr = currencyDrop.iterator();
    while (iteratorCurr.hasNext()){
        WebElement row = iteratorCurr.next();
        if (row.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(curr)){
            row.click();
        }
    }
```

и на if выбрасывает

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer valid (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Пробовал foreach, вместо итератора, тоже самое.

Comment: может Select использовать ?

Comment: А Select будет работать не с тегом Select? @ Senior Pomidor
`<ul class="rcbList" style="list-style: none;;">
<li class="rcbItem">UAH</li>
<li class="rcbItem">RUB</li>
<li class="rcbHovered">USD</li>
<li class="rcbItem">EUR</li></ul>`

Comment: да. только с этим тэгом.  а что за ListOfCurrency? это объект или переменая?

Comment: `By listOfCurrency = By.cssSelector( "#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucAmount_ddCurrency_DropDown>div>ul>li" );` вот так у меня реализовано @Senior Pomidor
Кстати если взять в try catch то тест проходит)

Comment: а что у вас делает row.click?

Comment: кликает по элементу, который соответсвует (curr, который я задал). Например curr = "USD" и row.getText() тоже USD